# Difference between quorum setups

Tags: windows-cluster

Three environments (LAB, DEV/TEST, PROD)  2 NODES (active, inactive), 7 ROLES.

Experiencing fail over issues on the PROD environment, but the LAB and DEV/TEST clusters are not experiencing the same issue.

QUORUM setups are different.

LAB - Witness: **Quorum Disk**

DEV/TEST - Witness : **Quorum Disk**

PROD - Witness : **Cluster Disk Quorum**

On the PROD system, under resources, the Q drive is a **Shared Storage - Dynamic Quorum**

On the LAB/DEV/TEST, under resources, the Q drive is a **normal letter drive**

Questions are...

1. What is the difference between a quorum type of **Quorum Disk** and **Cluster Disk Quorum**?
2. Should I have the same type of quorum setup on all three systems (this might be an obvious answer), with all three quorum type of normal drive letter, and not the Shared Storage type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the type of quorum disk from dynamic to a plain old drive partition.

no issues since.

Answer (score 0):

Production is a Dynamic Witness.  All are Disk Witness quorum types, and all clusters are Node Majority with Disk Witness.

A Dynamic Witness vote is toggled based on the number of votes.  If there are an odd number of votes, the witness doesn't have a vote. If there is an even number of votes, the witness has a vote. Dynamic witness significantly reduces the risk that the cluster will go down because of witness failure. The cluster decides whether to use the witness vote based on the number of voting nodes that are available in the cluster.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#dynamic-witness

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum